# How to open anullsrc input?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm trying:

```
    avformat_open_input(
        &input_context,
        "anullsrc",       
        NULL,
        NULL
    );
```

That however does not work and `input_context` remains NULL.

The 3rd argument, `NULL`, is an optional `AVInputFormat`.
https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#gac05d61a2b492ae3985c658f34622c19d

`fmt    If non-NULL, this parameter forces a specific input format. Otherwise the format is autodetected.`

I wanted to supply it by first creating the `AVInputFormat` with `av_find_input_format` - that however fails to find the format (`lavfi`), because it seems not to be registered in file `./libavformat/allformats.c` even though it exists in `./libavdevice/lavfi.c`.

## Edit

I might have found an issue. When I do:

```
$ ffmpeg -v 0 -demuxers | grep lavfi
```

The output is:

```
 D  lavfi           Libavfilter virtual input device
```

However, when I do:

```
main | grep lavfi
```

Where main is my program which includes:

```
    while ((fmt = av_demuxer_iterate(&i)))                                      
        printf("%s\n", fmt->name);
```

I get no output (I confirm that some demuxers are listed if I don't grep for lavfi).

So it seems then, that `libavformat.h` does not know about `lavfi` demuxer, whereas ffmpeg does. So it seems I need to fix this issue now.

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/asrc__anullsrc_8c_source.html might be relevant.

Comment: @AllanWind thank you but unfortunately I've seen it too many times today and to no effect. As in it does define what I need to use but I don't know how to use it through the (recommended?) public APIs. And there's global state, not exactly descriptive names, no comments, no verbose docs. I find it hard to understand the flow of data.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way.

I need to include:

```
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
```

Which allows me to do:

```
    const AVInputFormat *ifmt = NULL;

    while ((ifmt = av_input_audio_device_next(ifmt)))
    {
        printf("%s\n", ifmt->name);
        if (!strcmp(ifmt->name, "lavfi"))
            break;
    }
```

And then this works:

```
    AVFormatContext *ic = NULL;
    avformat_open_input(
        &ic,
        "anullsrc",       
        ifmt,
        NULL
    );
```